# Custom Entity Not Displaying in Custom Model-Driven App Navigation

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-uci, powerapps-modeldriven

In my sandbox environment I have created a new model-driven app which has its own solution. I've also created a custom entity and added it to the solution, along with Accounts and Contacts. When I load my app I see Accounts and Contacts in the navigation area on the left. Then I've edited my site map to include the custom entity and published. When I load my app now I still only see Accounts and Contacts. I even went as far as to remove contacts from the site map. After that my navigation still showed Accounts and Contacts.

What steps am I missing or messing up in the addition of this custom entity?

Comment: I have to guess - did you publish all customizations? same app and sitemap edited and tested ? is that entity privilege missing ?

Comment: I thought I did but will check again. I didn't think it would be privilege as I'm a System Administrator.

Comment: @ArunVinoth I had not added the site map to the solution. I totally forgot about that. Thanks for the prompts.

Comment: oh is this issue is between environments? I can post it as answer if you want to accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you are doing this troubleshooting steps.

1. Save/Publish the Sitemap and Model driven app. Ans also "Publish all customizations" to avoid any left overs
2. Verify if you are checking/editing the same App and its respective sitemap
3. Sitemap item (subarea) can be hidden using particular privilege and tick-off that it is not that case
4. If deploying to another environment, add the app and sitemap to the deploying solution